# Can two Urgot use their ultimate on each other simultaneously?

Tags: league-of-legends

Can two Urgot use their ultimate on each other simultaneously? I mean, I have always wondered what would end up happening if this occurs at the exact same time. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if they are out of range of each other, then both click to use it on each other they will activate at the same time.

Comment: Sort of relevant:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HmgnnOSaCQ

Comment: As @SIRCAVEC pointed out in the video, Scarner's ultimate STUN the target and both scarners get the stun. If we follow this logic, then Urgot's ult will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they cancel eachother if they are to do it at the same time, otherwise it comes down to who has a better internet connection, whos is fastest.

Comment: Can you provide some information about it? Assumptions are not good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Tested. Only one goes off, as the other is Suppressed. Red side seems to work more often.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested this yet or seen it occurring in a match:

But since Urgot ultimate does stun it's target, at least 1 of the two Urgot's will get interrupted, or 1 is stunned before he can start channeling his ultimate.